Cannot search for text that contains the letter 'f' in the PDF generated using PDFMake
I generated some words that contain the letter 'f' in the PDF generated using PDFMake, for example, "Waffle" or "Leflaive", but I am unable to search using any substrings that contain "fl".
var fonts = {
    Roboto: {
        normal: 'fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf',
        bold: 'fonts/Roboto-Medium.ttf',
        italics: 'fonts/Roboto-Italic.ttf',
        bolditalics: 'fonts/Roboto-MediumItalic.ttf'
    }
};

// Define the document definition
var docDefinition = {
    content: [
        { text: 'Waffle', font: 'Roboto' },
        { text: 'Lefaive', font: 'Roboto' }
    ],
    defaultStyle: {
        font: 'Roboto'
    }
};

// Create the PDF
pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).download('document.pdf');

I tried to use custom fonts but still ended up with the same issue. I love PDFMake and do not want to stop using this library because of this bug.
Please give me a hint. Thank you.

Most likely, your fl is getting replaced with the latin small ligature ﬂ, and that's why it doesn't get found any more, when you search for fl. So you'll have to see if that can be disabled; otherwise you might need to use a font that doesn't come with this "feature" in the first place.
